# Why did Cersei ask this of Jon?

Tags: game-of-thrones

In Season 7, Episode 7, Cersei asks the following

> The crown accepts your truce... In return, the King of the north will extend this truce. He will remain in the north where he belongs. He will not take up arms against the Lannisters. He will not choose sides.

She says she asks because she knows Jon, Ned Starks son, will tell the truth. She is proven right about that.

I'm lost on why ask though. Why does she care if he stays in the north? Why is she concerned with him in particular? Did she expect he would accept and keep that promise? Was this request pointless either way because...

> Cersei later reveals to Jamie that her plan was to play along with the truce and exploit it.

Why did Cersei make this request?

Comment: My answer wasn't convincing enough. So, deleted :D

Comment: @Dawny33 I read it. Was insightful but still left a lot of questions open. Thanks anyways!

Comment: The North is and has always been a true threat to Cersei, therefore getting them to not interfere is strategically sound. So it's not just about Jon, it's about the entire North.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Better question: Why would Cersei NOT ask this?

Best case, Jon really is a honorable fool like Ned, and

> after she inevatibly betrays Dany, Jon may feel honor-bound to not immediately retaliate. Even if Dany strikes first (or Cersei makes it look like that to Jon), Cersei may assume that Jon will help Dany anyways. After all, they both met first before reaching out to Cersei, so there obviously was some alliance-forging going on already. But maybe he will value honor higher than his personal affection, and truly stay neutral - at least long enough to allow Cersei to get an advantage.

Worst case, what could happen? It's a reasonable demand from the other side's perspective. If Jon declines, Cersei can just cede that point with no ill consequences (or demand something smaller, negotiation tactics 101).

In between, Jon might at least feel a little bit guilty in some way, and psychologically playing her enemies has always been a source of entertainment for Cersei.

Comment: It also is a good way to get the response she did, that Jon has declared for Dany. Cersei now knows this upfront.

Comment: Cersei also has the position and leverage to ask for SOMETHING, since she's being asked for a truce, and is conceding. Why not ask for the best thing she can? Splitting up her allies is way beyond worthwhile.

Answer (score 2):

Cersei knew Jon would never accept her conditions, so it was a win-win situation for her. She wanted to put the blame on Jon for not accepting the truce with the three sides. She showed off that she agreed to the terms of Daenerys but knowing Jon she cleverly made this condition.

Comment: I've just edited this to be a bit more accurate as I remember the scene. You can always roll back my edit if I was stepping on your toes a bit though!

Comment: i am sure this is more accurate version. Thanks !